# Detecting my own Firefox extension from a webpage

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, detection

I am trying to find an easy way to detect if my extension is installed in Firefox 3.6. This should be done from a webpage, probably using javascript.

I've read a lot of blogs that says that I should try loading an image from my extension. Since I own the extension, and I can write the code, that seems like an unnecessary hack.

I've also thought about setting a global variable to the web document, but I havn't been able to achieve this. I thought I would be able to write:

`top.window.content.document.hasMyPlugin = true`

but this is doesn't seem to work (hasMyPlugin is not defined). I only add this variable when visiting my domain (I have added a WebProgressListener and check the host property), so global namespace pollution shouldn't be a problem.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

The way I try to access the variable is simply `if(hasMyPlugin)` or `if(document.hasMyPlugin)`... Perhaps I'm accessing it the wrong way?

Comment: Have you been able to make your plugin alter the page DOM at all?  If you can do that, then you can definitely detect the effects from JavaScript code on the page. Be careful about the sequencing, however: make sure that whatever your page does to detect the plugin happens *after* the plugin makes its changes!

Comment: @Pointy Thanks. No I haven't, but I haven't had any reason to - my plugin isn't doing anything like that. I'm just wondering if there is something wrong with the code above, if it's *supposed* to work like that, or not. Then I can move on to troubleshooting the sequencing.

Comment: Well by "modifying the DOM" I meant doing something like adding a "class" value to the `<body>` tag.  Then you can just check for that in your JavaScript code on the page.

Comment: @Pointy I'd preferably not pollute the DOM in that way, surely there must be a "cleaner" way of detecting an extension that I own?

Comment: Well, it'd still be "polluting" the DOM, but you could set the in-page variable "hasMyPlugin" by injecting a `<script>` tag into the document for the purpose of defining it.

Comment: @Pointy Alright.. I give up ;) Could you please write a small, small example of how to inject the javascript, and making it run? Is there anything to take into account, given that I am doing stuff in the onLocationChanged callback? As an answer, and I'll gladly accept it.. :)

Comment: Well @Max, unfortunately I'm only barely familiar with plugin programming; all I've really done is write a few Greasemonkey scripts :-)  As I recall it, however, it's a slightly weird but mostly straightforward process - you go through more-or-less familiar DOM APIs like "createElement" and "append". Since messing with the DOM is such a common thing for plugins, it should hopefully be possible to find some samples written by a person (unlike me) who knows how to do it.

Comment: When do you check wether `hasMyPlugin` is true? It is very well possible that it is becomes true after the script checks it. Perhaps try to do it in a timed function that checks every `n` seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way is to make your extension react to a user-defined event. Your web page dispatches the event on an appropriate event target (you can use the document if you have nothing better) and then your extension's event listener can verify the web page address and perform an action. At the very minimum your event listener could call preventDefault() on the event; the web page could then call getPreventDefault() to see whether your extension is present.

Comment: Hey, thanks. This sounds like a great approach... Is it possible to add an eventhandler to ALL documents, or would I need to reattach my eventhandler on each new webpage?

Comment: @Max Just add your event handler to the chrome; the events bubble up.

Comment: Thanks! This didn't show me everything, but it got me on the right path, and your comment was very useful for my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

See here: [Allow content documents (web pages) to detect my Firefox addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089941/allow-content-documents-to-detect-my-firefox-addon)