# Selenium is unable to extract page source and returning empty body of html page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Here is my python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request as ul

from selenium import webdriver
style.use('ggplot')
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\\Phantomjs\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
def getBondRate():
    #driver.deleteAllCookies();
    url = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/index/tnx?countrycode=xx"  

    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    html = driver.page_source
    return html
bondRate = getBondRate()
print(bondRate)
```

Few days back it was reading perfectly fine from Market watch. Now it is returning nothing in Body tag. Is selenium not loading page?

Answer (score 0):

Do you require the HTML tags also? If not, you can try retrieving using the body tag. Here's how I would do it using Java.

```
String src=driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the url `https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/index/tnx?countrycode=xx` the behavior you are observing is pretty much justified.

I have taken up your code and along with a simple tweak tried to extract the `page_source` with **PhantomJS** as well as **ChromeDriver**. It is observed that when you use any *WebDriver* variant, the *WebDriver* **fingerprints** are geting detected and a **`Fingerprinting error`** is raised as follows:

- Error details:

  ```
  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  kpf.js?url=/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/fingerprint&token=058cbc6a-f8b8-f175-ca68-8c2e0fd6a4e3:1 Fingerprinting error 
    name: Error 
    message: Error issuing AJAX request (status code: 404) 
    stack: Error: Error issuing AJAX request (status code: 404)
      at XMLHttpRequest.N.a.onreadystatechange (https://www.marketwatch.com/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/fingerprint/script/kpf.js?url=/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/fingerprint&token=058cbc6a-f8b8-f175-ca68-8c2e0fd6a4e3:1:1884)
  DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://www.marketwatch.com/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/fingerprint/script/fingerprint.js.map
  ```
- DevTools Snapshot:

[image: fingerprintingerror]

- You can find a relevant discussions in:

  - [**`Browser Automation with Selenium: Fingerprints, recognizability and traceability?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653653/browser-automation-with-selenium-fingerprints-recognizability-and-traceability)
  - [**`Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)
  - [**`Selenium Webdriver is detectable`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938916/selenium-webdriver-is-detectable)

Comment: Thank you. How do I overcome with this issue if I still need to access data?

Comment: @JAGS8386 There are multiple ways. You can compile the _WebDriver_ binary i.e. _chromedriver_ binary with a few tweeks or use a _PROXY_. I have updated the answer and added some more references.

Comment: @JAGS8386 were you able to overcome the kpf.js with Selenium or any other tool?